Chaining routes using NewServeMux
I'm using Go's standard library and trying to register multiple HTTP handlers with http.NewServeMux. However, I've encountered an issue where only the route /reservation/cancel is registered, while other routes ending with / (like /) are not.
Here’s the code I’m using to register the handlers:
func (dep *ReservationHandler) Register() {
    ware := middleware.RequestBodyMiddleware[model.ReservationPayload]{Logger: dep.logger}
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("GET /", dep.availableDates)
    mux.Handle("POST /", ware.RequestBody(http.HandlerFunc(dep.create)))
    mux.HandleFunc("POST /cancel/{reservation_id}", dep.cancel)

    dep.mux.Handle("/reservation/", http.StripPrefix("/reservation", mux))

}

Note that when I use the following approach, everything works as expected:
func (dep *ReservationHandler) Register() {
    ware := middleware.RequestBodyMiddleware[model.ReservationPayload]{Logger: dep.logger}

    dep.mux.HandleFunc("GET /reservation", dep.availableDates)
    dep.mux.Handle("POST /reservation", ware.RequestBody(http.HandlerFunc(dep.create)))
    dep.mux.HandleFunc("POST /reservation/cancel/{reservation_id}", dep.cancel)
}

Why is it that the routes with / at the end aren't registered in the first example, but the ones with explicit /reservation work fine?
EDIT (a reproducible sample)
handler.go
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

// Handler registers all endpoints
type Handler struct {
    mux *http.ServeMux
}

func (dep *Handler) serve() *http.ServeMux {
    r := reservationHandler{mux: dep.mux}
    r.register()
    return dep.mux
}

type reservationHandler struct {
    mux *http.ServeMux
}

func (dep *reservationHandler) register() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("POST /", dep.create)
    mux.HandleFunc("POST /cancel/{reservation_id}", dep.cancel)
    mux.HandleFunc("GET /", dep.dates)
    dep.mux.Handle("/reservation/", http.StripPrefix("/reservation", mux))

    //dep.mux.HandleFunc("GET /reservation", dep.dates)
    //dep.mux.HandleFunc("POST /reservation", dep.create)
    //dep.mux.HandleFunc("POST /reservation/cancel/{reservation_id}", dep.cancel)
}

type payload struct {
    ReservationId string `json:"reservation_id"`
    Name          string `json:"name"`
}

func (dep *reservationHandler) dates(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("all reservation dates handler called")

    obj := payload{ReservationId: "res-1", Name: "res-name"}

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

    response, _ := json.Marshal(obj)
    if _, err := w.Write(response); err != nil {
        log.Printf(err.Error())
    }
}

func (dep *reservationHandler) create(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("reservation create handler called")

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)

    if _, err := w.Write([]byte("new reservation created")); err != nil {
        log.Printf(err.Error())
    }
}

func (dep *reservationHandler) cancel(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id, err := strconv.ParseInt(r.PathValue("reservation_id"), 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("cancellation handler error")
        http.Error(w, "invalid reservation id", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    log.Printf("reservation cancellation handler with id %v called", id)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
}


main.go
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    h := Handler{mux: http.NewServeMux()}

    log.Print("server starting on port :8080")
    server := http.Server{
        Addr:              ":8080",
        WriteTimeout:      10 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:       30 * time.Second,
        ReadHeaderTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:       5 * time.Second,
        Handler:           h.serve(),
    }

    log.Fatal("server failed to start ", server.ListenAndServe())
}


How do you know which routes are registered? Please provide a minimal, reproducible example.

@eik I just edited my example with a reproducible sample.

The following test code works for me:
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

func TestCancellation(t *testing.T) {
    h := Handler{mux: http.NewServeMux()}

    ts := httptest.NewServer(h.serve())
    defer ts.Close()

    resp, err := http.Post(ts.URL+"/reservation/cancel/0", "", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusNoContent {
        t.Errorf("Got status %d, expected %d", resp.StatusCode, http.StatusNoContent)
    }
}

So I'm not sure what “aren't registered” means in your context.
Generally, your handlers should not have access to the underlying http.ServeMux. Use it as arguments of a function rather than a member of a structure, this will be less confusing.

The purpose of creating a mux in the register function is to enable chaining of routes. For instance, a higher-level mux/path could be prefixed with /api/v1/, while nested muxes inheriting from the higher-level mux can define their own subroutes, such as /api/v1/register or /api/v1/hello.
